# How to configure paypal sandbox for testing

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

We have an IPN listener already from integration of another paypal api.  Now I want am trying to intregate a payment button to a web soolution, which should then be able to report to the existing IPN listener.

I have a login to the paypal devlopers site.  I see the IPN simulator there but as I understand it that allows me to create  a message and send it manually.  Is there any way to configure my sandbox account to send IPN notifications to the listener when I send a click from the web button to the sandbox.  In other words I want the IPN message to be created based on the info I send with the web button, in the same way as it would in the live system, not to be my guess as to what message will be created then.  I don't see where to configure the address I want notifications sent to other than for the simulator.

Also, is there any way to test with a currency other than USD?

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IPN, the easiest way is to pass the URL of your IPN handler in the `notify_url` variable of your button.

Currency codes can be tested by passing the currency code in the `currency_code` variable of your button.  A list of currencies PayPal supports can be found at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/ .

Comment: Thanks.  The currency question was more for the IPN Simulator, but it appears that this only supports USD.  When I make actual requests I can set the currency and get the IPN message OK in other currencies.  Gave up on getting the simulator to work eventually and just did a bunch of actual payments via sandbox.